# Can a women's mikvah be used to immerse vessels?

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath, tevilas-keilim-dipping

What happens if a vessel/container drops into a women's mikvah. Does it render it invalid?

Thank you!

Comment: The title and the body of the question do not match. Please edit to show why you might think that using a mikvah for keilim might not be valid or invalidate it for people. There is no reason to think that a regular mikvah cannot also be used for keilim.

Comment: @saba How do you know there is no such reason?

Comment: These are two completely separate questions. One question per post please.

Answer (score 1):

A mikvah for vessels has the same requirements as a  women's mikvah. As it says [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1230791/jewish/Immersion-of-Vessels-Tevilat-Keilim.htm)

> This is interpreted by the Talmud to mean that the vessels should be
>   purified by immersion in the waters used by a niddah for her
>   purification—a mikvah.

So a women's mikvah can be used to immerse vessels.

If  a vessel/container drops into a women's mikvah, it does not render it invalid. See [Mishnayos Mikvaos Perek 7](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01274.html#HtmpReportNum0044_L2) where the possible ways of invalidating a mikvah are mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless it causes so much water to splash out that there are no longer 40 *seah* left (which is fairly unlikely).  If it's kosher for women it's certainly kosher for keilim (other than that the owners might not be happy about its use as a keilim mikva, which could raise its own halachik issues.)

Comment: I dont get the kal vahomer

Comment: @DoubleAA karet

Comment: What does karet have to do with anything? Does the Mikva then also work for a Zav because there is no prohibition on relations with him at all?